# how to edit a dictionary value in python that have a dictionary as a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary in python that has a key and a dictionary as a value like that

```
a = ('emp1','emp2')
b = ({'dep':'', 'sal':''})
comp = dict.fromkeys(a,b)
print(comp)
comp['emp1']['dep'] = 'IT'
comp['emp1']['sal'] = '300$'
print(comp)
```

and the output is like that

```
{'emp1': {'dep': '', 'sal': ''}, 'emp2': {'dep': '', 'sal': ''}}
{'emp1': {'dep': 'IT', 'sal': '300$'}, 'emp2': {'dep': 'IT', 'sal': '300$'}}
```

why all the values are changing if I'm trying to chang the ***value*** only for ***`"emp1"`***
can any one help ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

> `fromkeys()` is a class method that returns a new dictionary. *value* defaults to `None`. All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for *value* to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.

So, both the keys point to the same dictionary that you are trying to change.

You can use this instead:

```
comp = {key: {'dep': '', 'sal': ''} for key in ('emp1', 'emp2')}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the comp['emp1] and comp['emp2] actually refer to the same object.
You can verify it by id() function which returns the unique identifier of the python object

```py
a = ('emp1', 'emp2')
b = ({'dep': '', 'sal': ''})
comp = dict.fromkeys(a, b)
print(id(comp["emp1"]))
print(id(comp["emp2"]))
print(comp)
comp['emp1']['dep'] = 'IT'
comp['emp1']['sal'] = '300$'
print(comp)
```

it returns

```
4467496912
4467496912
{'emp1': {'dep': '', 'sal': ''}, 'emp2': {'dep': '', 'sal': ''}}
{'emp1': {'dep': 'IT', 'sal': '300$'}, 'emp2': {'dep': 'IT', 'sal': '300$'}}
```

If u have to use fromkeys, The solution is

```
from copy import deepcopy
a = ('emp1', 'emp2')
b = ({'dep': '', 'sal': ''})
comp = dict.fromkeys(a, b)
comp = {key: deepcopy(b) for key in comp}
print(id(comp["emp1"]))
print(id(comp["emp2"]))
print(comp)
comp['emp1']['dep'] = 'IT'
comp['emp1']['sal'] = '300$'
print(comp)
```

the output will be what u want

```
4300371360
4301322592
{'emp1': {'dep': '', 'sal': ''}, 'emp2': {'dep': '', 'sal': ''}}
{'emp1': {'dep': 'IT', 'sal': '300$'}, 'emp2': {'dep': '', 'sal': ''}}
```