# List of Dictionaries Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
lst = []

dct = {
    "key": "",
    "value": ""
}

for i in range(10):
    dct["key"] = i
    dct["value"] = i
    lst.append(dct)

lst
>>[{'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}]
```

I am getting this output for this code. what is going on here! The output shouldn't be different? like

```
[{'key': 1, 'value': 1}, {'key': 2, 'value': 2}, {'key': 3, 'value': 3}]......
```

Comment: Think about how many dictionaries in total you create in this code, and how many different dictionaries are added to the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to edit a dictionary value in python that have a dictionary as a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474564/how-to-edit-a-dictionary-value-in-python-that-have-a-dictionary-as-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create a dictionary like you did in the beginning. You could create dictionaries and append them to the list within the loop.

```py
lst = []
for i in range(10):
    d = {'key':i+1, 'value':i+1}
    lst.append(d)
print(lst)
```

**Output :**

```
[{'key': 1, 'value': 1}, {'key': 2, 'value': 2}, {'key': 3, 'value': 3}, {'key': 4, 'value': 4}, {'key': 5, 'value': 5}, {'key': 6, 'value': 6}, {'key': 7, 'value': 7}, {'key': 8, 'value': 8}, {'key': 9, 'value': 9}, {'key': 10, 'value': 10}]
```

Comment: got it! thanks. so it means the list object using the dict instance memory reference instead of value?

Comment: The list just contains the 10 dictionaries. I think each of them have different memory locations.